# Select Query with Conditional Check for group of records

Tags: sql, impala

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t2.cmdb_id,
    t1.src_sys_id,
    t3.appl_nm,
    t1.st_mgmnt_cd Status,
    CASE 
       WHEN t1.st_mgmnt_cd != "PURGE" 
          THEN 'In-Progress' 
       ELSE 'In-Compliance' 
    END as Status,
    t1.podium_delivery_date
FROM
    table1 t1 
JOIN 
    table2 t2 
JOIN 
    table3 t3 
WHERE
    t1.src_sys_id = t2.ingstn_nm 
    AND t2.cmdb_id = t3.cmdb_id
```

The above query returns many rows where the status column is repeated. This is because on the original table, I have many states other than purge for the column `st_mgmnt_cd`. But I need to do the check for all records under a `cmdb_id`. Hence for a `cmdb_id`, I need to have only one row in the results and status shown based on check.

How can I rewrite the query to do the check across the records of a `cmdb_id`?

```
cmdb_id schema_name        appl_nm  status  assessment_date
88      PAD                PADCOD   HOT     20180601
88      PAD                PADCOD   WARM    20180601
218     EED                EEDCOD   HOT     20180617
218     EED                EEDCOD   WARM    20180618
218     EED                EEDCOD   COLD    20180620
3106    ABC                ABCOD    HOT     20180601
3106    ABC                ABCOD    WARM    20180604
3106    ABC                ABCOD    EXPIRED 20180620
3106    ABC                ABCOD    PURGE   20180622
```

Results expected
 ==================

```
 88   PAD   PADCOD  In-Progress     20180601
 218  EED   EEDCOD  In-Progress     20180620
 3106 ABC   ABCOD   In-Compliance   20180620
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: sure will put test data

Comment: cmdb_id schema_name appl_nm status assessment_date
88  PAD          PADCOD HOT    20180601
88  PAD          PADCOD WARM         20180601
218  EED          EEDCOD HOT  20180617
218  EED           EEDCOD WARM         20180618
218  EED          EEDCOD COLD         20180620
3106 ABC          ABCOD HOT  20180601
3106 ABC                 ABCOD WARM 20180604
3106 ABC    ABCOD EXPIRED 20180620
3106 ABC   ABCOD PURGE 20180622
 
 
 Results expected
 ==================
 88   PAD PADCOD  In-Progress   20180601
 218  EED EEDCOD In-Progress  20180620
 3106 ABC ABCOD   In-Compliance  20180620

Comment: You can edit your question and paste your sample data:)

Comment: So basically i need the query to loop thru each group of records for a cmdb_id and then have the status field populated. Only one entry for each cmdb_id

Comment: What's `assessment_date` from your expect result and `assessment_date` type is datetime?

Comment: assessment_date is the date which the state of record was changed. We need to choose the latest data across each cmdb_id set of records. Then for this date all the records will have a st_mgmnt_cd. Based on that we need to derive In-Progress or In-compliance.

Comment: If you really just want those five columns I get the impression a simple `group by cmdb_id` would do along with an aggregate of `min` or `max` on the `case` expression.

Comment: This is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] question, and the standard formats should all work.  Note that you have a mismatch in your expected results - the date listed for `3106` was not the date for that status!

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your query in a SELECT an change to max(st_mgmntcd)  in internal query.

Ie
SELECT COL1, data FROM(
SELECT COL1, MAX(REPETINGCOL) as data group by COL1) x

Comment: yep, thats the way to go, a little generic answer but thats it, ill do a little more specific answer :)

Comment: No this isn't - `max(st_mgmntcd)` will presumably return `"WARM"`, because it's sorting alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

For the future: use something live-testable

Like [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/47MnGFEsGvz9V1G5jK1YSR/0)

I left out the joins to other tables and added a field `id` to join the table `temp` but you should get the concept. :)

Assumed you want the most current entry for each `cmdb_id`. I used the new field `id`for this but you could use the field `podium_delivery_date` in the same manner.

```
# assume joins have been made
SELECT
    t1.cmdb_id,
    t1.appl_nm,
    t1.st_mgmnt_cd Status,
    CASE 
       WHEN t1.st_mgmnt_cd != "PURGE" 
          THEN 'In-Progress' 
       ELSE 'In-Compliance' 
    END as Status,
    t1.podium_delivery_date
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN 
      (SELECT
          tx.cmdb_id,
          MAX(tx.id) as highest_id_of_group
      FROM
          table1 tx
      GROUP BY
          tx.cmdb_id) as temp
    ON temp.highest_id_of_group = t1.id
```

Remember to put good indexes!

Comment: Thank you friends. So i got better clarity of the requirement. I need to get the latest time stamp record against each application and then join it with other tables to display the information.